# TortiseHg : remove items from Clone dialog Source list

Tags: tortoisehg

In the TortiseHG Clone dialog I want to delete  items from the list used to populate the source combo box list. I suspect there is a file where the list items acculate that can be edited.

Comment: What is your question ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to remove the previous entries (as far as I know, but there could be some history file in install directory that can be edited), however TortoiseHG only keeps a history of the last 10 clones - you could just use different source repos to clone until the one you want to delete is no longer in the history.

Answer (score 0):

The recent clone list (among other things) is stored in your roaming profile in the `TortoiseHgQt.ini` file.

On Windows 8.1, I can find it at `C:\Users\{user account}\AppData\Roaming\TortoiseHg\TortoiseHgQt.ini`